# Update existing table by migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a database created by "database first" approach. But now I want to update records in the specific table by "code first" approach, by migrations. I can insert records by using EntityTypeBuilder.HasData() in IEntityTypeConfiguration instance, but how to update existing records?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [migrationBuilder.Sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.migrations.migrationbuilder.sql?view=efcore-3.1) command to execute pure SQL-expressions during migration:

```
 protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
 {
    migrationBuilder.Sql("Your UPDATE sentence here");
 }
```

Comment: Ok, but I'll need to update records not once, and by few members of the team. So what the flow in this case? Add a dummy migration and edit it manually each time?

Comment: Here https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/migrations/seeding#amending-seed-data is written a seeded data can be changed between migrations but I didn't check it myself.

Comment: Thats the thing - I don't have seeded data in the code, cause it was "database first" approach. The data is only in the database now.